# Sending an email which present a blade.php with a HTML form

Tags: html, forms, laravel, email

In Laravel 5.3 I'm sending an email which present a blade.php HTML file. Inside this blade a have a form with a action to a route which is a put. This form is to confirm something, but my form and submit button does not work when clicking in the received email.

What I have tried so far:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://....dk/public/api/company/{{$company_id}}/user/{{$user_id}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
  <input type="submit" value="Acceptere invitationen fra {{$company}}">
</form>
```

Comment: Just use an <a> tag instead of form for an email.

Comment: Hi @LarsMertens thx for replying, but I'm not quite sure what you mean? Like this <a method="POST" action="http://....dk...

Comment: Lars is saying you don't need to use a form tag for a simple button

Comment: But the link is to a rest API which is a PUT method. How can i define the PUT method without a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just link users to the page like this

```
<a href="http://....dk/public/api/company/{{$company_id}}/user/{{$user_id}}">Acceptere invitationen fra {{$company}}</a>
```

Instead of post in routes.php use get method instead. Form is not supported by a lot off mail clients. So if you target a larger audience i would suggest using the supported anchor tag.